# Return value or false by TryGetValue method

Tags: dictionary, f#

I have a dictionary and get the value:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let price = Dictionary<string, int>()
Array.iter price.Add [|"apple", 5; "orange", 10|]
let buy key = price.TryGetValue(key) |> snd |> (<)
printfn "%A" (buy "apple" 7)
printfn "%A" (buy "orange" 7)
printfn "%A" (buy "banana" 7)
```

> true
>
> false
>
> true

I need false in 3th call. How to get value or `false` if key is not found? The problem is that `TryGetValue` returns `true` or `false` depends on `key` is found or not, but value is returned by reference.

Comment: The hint is to change `snd |> (<)` to something a little more com,plicated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It'll make your life easier if you define an Adapter for `TryGetValue` that is more F#-like:

```
let tryGetValue k (d : Dictionary<_, _>) =
    match d.TryGetValue k with
    | true, v -> Some v
    | _ -> None
```

With this, you can now define the `buy` function like this:

```
let buy key limit =
    price |> tryGetValue key |> Option.map ((>=) limit) |> Option.exists id
```

This gives you the desired result:

```
> buy "apple" 7;;
val it : bool = true
> buy "orange" 7;;
val it : bool = false
> buy "banana" 7;;
val it : bool = false
```